# axios-retry with custom retry option

Tags: node.js, axios, axios-retry

I'm having issues with axios retry. It is not retrying, it returns response after first time it fails.

```
await axios.get(`${URL}/test`, {
    'axios-retry': {
        retries: 3
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
})
.then(async (response) => {
    //console.log(response);
    return res.json(response.data);
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log("Error: " + err);
    return res.json("ERROR");
});
```

At the first error console log, it stops and return the `ERROR`. I also, would like to set the some retry "custom" conditions. For example, if the response.data is an empty string, I would like to retry. Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Given that you are using `axios-retry`, there is a note in their repo:
Not working with axios 0.19.0. For details see the bug. axios 0.19.1 has fixed this bug. Also I'm adding here but I believe you are surely doing this configuration before the calls:
axiosRetry(axios, { retries: 3 }); (Passing the axios instance to axiosRetry), retries defaults to 3 according to the documentation.

Comment: Could you show me an example?

Comment: I can paste the documentation here for you: https://github.com/softonic/axios-retry